# Identify virtual instrument and preset

Tags: replication, instruments, vsti

One of the tracks of the Osomatsu-san anime series soundtrack uses a virtual instrument (some kind of distorted strings) that sounds familiar. For example it is used in Episode 3 starting around 03:15.

Example: https://clyp.it/den3kc0p

Can you identify the software and preset?

Answer (score 1):

To me it sounds like an up/down arpeggiated saw synth. 
It does sound pretty much digital and I'm sure you can achieve a similar sound in most commercially available software or hardware based synths

There is also a lot of reverb on the sound effects in background that sound pad-ish

Comment: Yeah, this should be fairly easy to replicate in any number of softsynths that have controllable resonance and a simple envelope generator. It's not too far off from the default settings in Logic's ES-P, for example.